# Where is 1.5 GiB of my RAM going in Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, 64-bit

I have 8 GiB of physical memory, but only 6.56 GiB of it is available. See the screenshot below:

[image]

It is not shared with an onboard video card - I have a NVidia NVS 3100M video card with 512 MiB of its own RAM. It is also not limited by 32-bit, obviously, or it would be 4 GiB.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
**FACEPALM**

In a previous laptop I was missing a bunch of RAM due to 64-bit issues and I thought that it was that field that showed the difference, but as people pointed out that's just the *actually free* RAM.  That's what I get for not checking resmon.exe :P

Comment: What is that a screenshot *of*?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg It's the System Summary from System Information. The Available Physical Memory is the sum of Standby and Free memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry robin, it says out of 8gb, 6.56gb is free at the moment, rest is used by Windows(OS) and other background processes

Comment: This is correct. "Available" refers to the amount of memory that is immediately available for use by any program that requires it. The amount of RAM unavailable for Windows is the difference between the "Installed" and "Total" numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the screenshot, you have 8GBs RAM (Total) and 6.5 (Free).
You can check where your 1.5 GBs are in the task manager. Select Processes tab and order by memory to see what applications use the most.
Consider that windows OS is also taking few hundred MBs (or 1GB+).